# Rooms and people expected value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have $x$ number of rooms. I have $7x$ people.

One by one, each person randomly and independently chooses a room to enter. Multiple people can choose the same room.

What's the expected number of rooms that are never entered? What's the expected number of rooms that are entered exactly $y$ times such that $1 \leq y \leq x - 1$?

Comment: It seems quite complicated to me, so I would try a solution with simulation.

Comment: For me it seems that there is equal propability for each room that hooman will choos it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected value of a certain room be empty is the probability of this$$
\left( 1-\frac1x\right)^{7x}.
$$
By linearity of expectation the expected number of empty rooms is
$$x\left( 1-\frac1x\right)^{7x}.
$$

Comment: For the second question I'm thinking of using the binomial distribution, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Yes you are right. Just use $\binom {7x}y(\frac1x)^y(1-\frac1x)^{7x-y}$.